# how to combine two result sets without nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, subquery

I have two result sets that I would like to combine , since I would like to send them as a dataset to my ssrs report.

I am currently doing :

```
Select Sum(Teamsales) as TS, Null as PS from ABC;
 union 
Select null as TS, Sum(ProdSales) From DEF;
```

I get an output like this :

```
   123    NULL
   NULL   456
```

Is there a way I can get an output as below ??

```
 123  456
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Sum(Teamsales) as TS, 
(
  SELECT Sum(ProdSales) 
  FROM DEF 
) AS PS
FROM ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
select
  sum(teamsales) as ts,
  Sum(ProdSales) as ps
from
  abc cross join
  def
```

(Crossjoins are generally evil... But you could consider maybe to use more strict one.)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you would be having more than one row in each result set.
As you would apply a dimension in group by clause.

for example

You want to get total Team Sales and total Product sales for each branch then you should write.

```
Select ABC.BranchID, ABC.TS, DEF.PS
(Select BranchID, Sum(Teamsales) as TS from ABC group by BranchID) ABC
Inner Join
(Select BranchID, Sum(ProdSales) as PS From DEF group by BranchID) DEF
On ABC.BranchID = DEF.BranchID
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these are both one-liners, you could just cross-join the results, giving you a single line:

```
SELECT SUM(Teamsales) as TS, 
FROM   abc
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUMN(ProdSales) FROM def) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sum(TS), sum(PS) from (
Select Sum(Teamsales) as TS, Null as PS from ABC
 union all
Select null as TS, Sum(ProdSales) as PS From DEF
) as x
```